# Spline auto UV not working

Tags: texturing, uv, vector-mapping, splines

I'm trying to add a simple repeating patter to an extruded spline by clicking "Use UV values as Generated Texture Coordinates" and also using "Generated" mapping in Cycles. Howeever nothing happens at all, texture is still not mapped correctly. I couldn't find any solutions, all questions show this scheme to be working. Could anyone please help?

Thank you!
[image: a blender issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Viewport preview is not supported](https://developer.blender.org/T51886) for bezier curve objects automatic texture coordinates except *Object*, at least for 2.7# series, this [may change in future versions](https://developer.blender.org/D2986) but for the time being it is a known limitation. Both *Generated* and *Use UV for Mapping* options are only visible while rendering in Cycles/Blender Internal, OpenGL support does not display these.

You also seem to misunderstand how to use those coordinates. If you activate *Use UV for Mapping* you must use *UV* type coordinates in your node setup, not *Generated*.

Comment: Ok, thank you! It worked, at least I've got the texture showing. Unfortunately for some reason it doesn't stretch evenly though, it was a spiral originally and I moved few points at the ends and now the texture is more tight at the spiral itself and is stretched towards the ends. Is there any way to "reset" the UV? https://i.imgur.com/ufXdvNC.jpg

Comment: That is another limitation of the current it works. For better UV Map you have to convert to mesh and manually unwrap